# To find unit digit at a particular index of fibonacci series in O(1) time. (fibonacci series may be <=10^18)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, fibonacci

This code give wrong output above 10^7 input. can any body help me to solve this problem?

```
from math import sqrt,floor,log
def fib(N):
    var = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
    return round(pow(var, N) / sqrt(5))


test = int(input())

a=floor(log(test,2))
b=2**a
a=b%60
print(fib(a-1)%10)
```

Comment: Well binet's formula is not precise cause we can't represent irrational numbers with infinite precision cause of hardware limitations. I do not know if this is even solvable in O(1) such that it's always correct for any input, though you can do this in O(log N) using matrix exponentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fibonacci series has a cycle of 60 for its unit digit (without getting deep into map you can see that after 60 you get 1 and 1 again, so the sum would be 2 and so on).
Therefore, you can prepare a list of these Fibonacci unit digits:

```
fib_digit = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 4, 1, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 9, 0, 9, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 0, 3, 3, 6, 9, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9, 1, 0]
```

and return `fib_digit[N % 60]` in O(1).

Comment: +1. And note that although the specific value "60" is not obvious without trying it out, it is immediately clear that the cycle-length can't be longer than 100, because there are only 100 possible pairs of unit digits. So this is a figure-out-able solution, not just a weird magic trick. :-)